# How to minimize CPU wait time and CPU utilization when more static data is added into the Application?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, cpu

After adding more Static Data into the Oracle Database like more Entities/Accounts and other stuff it seems that the Application behaviour seems to slow down . The CPU wait cycles have increased and Apache Tomcat is also consuming more memory . Please some one advise how to minimize the Performance and let me know if anything else needs to be stated ?? Thanks in advance .

Comment: Use singleton and initialize only the Heavy Classes when used at first time.

Comment: Improve your code. If you want someone to help, improve your question. The answer may be anything. Maybe add DB indexes? Maybe remove rarely used indexes? Use batch statements? Add caching? Uninstall antivirus? Switch from 220V to 380V? *You told us nothing about what you're doing.*

Comment: ok ...I understand that that's the reason I asked what else I should be adding .....please leave the coding part aside because application was behaving fine and I have added more data into our Oracle DB for which CPU waits have increased .....I am looking for more performance tuning advise related stuff ....Thanks

Comment: From your last comment, it seems the application is bounded on the side of the database. Optimizing the DB (Indexes, partitions, etc) and tweaking the DBMS might help.